# Time needed to generate all of bits in a packet... why is the packet size divided by data size?

Tags: network-programming

I'm learning packet switching system and trying to understand this problem
from a text book. It's about the time needed to generate all of bits in a packet. What we learned so far was calculating a delay time that happens after a packet was made so time for making a packet feels new. Can anyone help me understand why they divided packet sizes by data size in the solution?

Information)
"Host A converts analog voice to a digital `64 kpbs` bit stream on the
fly.
Host A then groups the bits into `56 byte` packets."

Answer) `56*8 / 64*1000 = 7msec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are calculating *the time needed to generate all of bits in a packet*.

Each new bit is added to the packet until the packet is full. The full packet
will then be sent on its way, and a new empty packet will be created to hold the
next set of bits. Once it fills up, it will be sent also.

This means that each packet will contain bits that range from brand new ones, to
bits that have been waiting around for up to 7ms. (The age of the oldest bit in
the packet is important, because it contributes to the observed latency of the
application.)

Your bits are being created in a stream, at a fixed rate of 64*1000 bits per
second. In one second, 64,000 bits would be generated. Therefore, one bit is
generated every 1/64,000 = 0.016 milliseconds.

Those bits are being assembled into packets where each packet contains exactly
56*8 bits. If each bit took 0.016 milliseconds to create, then all 56*8 bits
will be created in approximately 7 milliseconds.

I like to sanity-check this kind of formula by looking at the units: BITS / SECOND.

56*8 BITS / 0.007 SECONDS = 66,286 BITS/SECOND which is approximately your bitrate.

If BITRATE = BITS / SECONDS then by simple algebra, SECONDS = BITS / BITRATE

Comment: This is a simple and great explanation...Thank you!